# Why MATLAB reads the data-rows in text file as data-columns initially?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I've a text file 'Data.txt' such as:-

```
S.No.   Date   Amplitude
```

The subsequent columns are separated by space rather than commas. Now, going through the tutorial provided in MATLAB webpage, I made a program such as:-

```
fileID = fopen('Data.txt','r');
formatSpec = '%d %d %f';
sizeA = [3 Inf];
A = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec,sizeA);
A=A';
```

This program works successfully in extracting data from the text file, after making some additional manipulations.

My question is- why it was suggested to keep

`sizeA = [3 Inf];`

rather than `[Inf 3]`
because this resulted in an initial generation of A matrix with a data row corresponding to S.No. 1 as column 1, next data row (corresponding to S.No. 2) as column 2, and so on.
At last, A was transposed to get a similar view of data, as given in the text file.
This transpose was necessary, I get it, but why an initial size was taken as such? 
I took

`sizeA = [Inf 3];`

and it resulted in an error.

So basically, I wanted to know the reason of such a size selection, and why not the other way around.